# LibreOffice how to add a rating using dots

Tags: libreoffice, rating

I'm need to rate things on a scale from 1 to 5, 1 being the lowest and 5 the highest rating using dots in a table.

```
a        xxx
b        x
c        xxxxx
```

where the x are placeholders for dots. So far my attempt was to place a separate table in each line and adding bullet points. Unfortunately empty lines with bullets, for some reason do a line break an ruin the visual appearance. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert the corresponding Unicode character into the document.

Examples could be •, or ★, or☆.
Just copy paste them into the document.
Or use the insert symbol dialogue (i think it is *insert -> special character*, I don't have an installation at hand now).

There are plenty of websites, where you can browse for Unicode glyphs. For example https://www.utf8icons.com/character/8226/bullet

Comment: if you know how it goes its obvious but searching on goole like libreoffice and bullets or dots brings um no real result, thx for your help